# $request->get() not getting the form value when updating data in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to update just one column from'business_account' table. I tried something like bellow, When trying to get the form value to my 'packPurchasedMembers' controller function I am getting null value. What should be the right code to getting expected result.

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'super', 'middleware' => 'super', 'as' => 'super.'], function () {
       Route::post('verify-account', array('as' => 'verify-account', 'uses' => 'packPurchasedMembers@postVerifyAccount'));});
```

My Controller-

```
    public function postVerifyAccount(Request $request){            
        $uid     = $request->get('userid');
        $verfiy  = $request->get('verification');
          DB::table('business_account')
                  ->where('user_id', $uid)
                  ->update(['verified' => $verfiy]);}
```

My Form -

```
              <div class="pull-left">
                    <h4>Verify Account</h4>
                    @foreach ($verification as $verify)
                    <form action="{{ url('super/verify-account') }}" method="POST">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" />

                          <input type="radio" id="reinv1" name="verification" value="0"
                          <?php if ($verify->verified == '0') echo 'checked' ?> >
                              <label for="reinv1"> Not Verified</label>
                          <input type="radio" id="reinv2" name="verification" value="1"
                          <?php if ($verify->verified == '1') echo 'checked' ?> >
                              <label for="reinv2"> Verified</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    @endforeach
              </div>
```

Comment: Its $request->input('name'); Also make sure that you have use of Request class. Again get -> is Symfony style, input->laravel style of coding. My preference is input

Comment: Tried, but getting error, even error not showing in laravel.log

Comment: Can you please post the error

Comment: I could not find the error..I checked in laravel.log

Comment: Can you check your php.ini whether the error reporting is enabled or not. If yes then even you can set the path to store the errors.

Comment: I checked php.ini and enabled the error_reporting then restarted the server and getting the same situation , I added {{ csrf_field() }} in html form also.

Comment: Dude function name or variable name must not contain hypen(-)  in between them. Instead of verify-account can you try verify_account. Hope fully that may the problem in Route. Can you please add echo  inside the verifyAccount function to check whether the post is getting submitted to function or not

Comment: I added echo inside the verifyAccount function getting same "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" and I used verify-account as my route name.

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable time. Now getting the expected results. I used get in my route, now post is working for me.

Comment: Cheers. Good to know you got it working

Comment: Cheers. thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following function to retrieve input value

```
public function postVerifyAccount(Request $request){            
    $uid     = $request->input('userid');
    $verfiy  = $request->input('verification');
      DB::table('business_account')
              ->where('user_id', $uid)
              ->update(['verified' => $verfiy]);
}
```

Comment: Tried, but getting something wrong, I checked laravel.log to find the error, but getting nothing. blade saying just 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.'

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in env and restart your laravel application to enable log

Comment: Now When submitting form it's showing 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

Comment: Which means the form was submitted in `GET` method instead of `POST` method, So laravel can't find correct route. Please add blade file for reference

Comment: I already added my blade file like form remains in 'show-details.blade.php'

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable time. Now getting the expected results. I used get in my route, now post is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone lands up to this question. I would like to address the solution for the above question.

So the problem was he had not used the proper HTTP request. Instead of using **POST** request he was using **GET** request.

In **routes/web.php**

The request method is changed from GET -> POST.

Hope it may help someone.